# Running Ubunutu in VM, laptop overheats when idle, how to reduce power usage?

Tags: virtualbox, overheating

I am running Ubuntu on a VM using Virtual Box, but my Spectre x360 (Windows host OS) overheats even when i'm just simply using a text editor.

I am a bit new, is there a way to check why this is happening, and to reduce the amount of power it is using?